# Hacer una conversación entre 3 personas y que después por medio de un menú pueda cambiar los saludos y el orden de estos

Tags: java, array, switch

```
public class CharlaMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner Leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Creando la instancia del objeto 
        Persona Amigo1 = new Persona();
        Persona Amigo2 = new Persona();
        Persona Amigo3 = new Persona();
        Persona[] Fulanos = new Persona[3];
        
        //Inicializando los atributos Texto... de los 3 objetos Persona
        Amigo1.TextoSaludo = "Amigo1: Buenos Dias";
        Amigo2.TextoSaludo = "Amigo2: Que Onda?";
        Amigo3.TextoSaludo = "Amigo3: Saludos";
        
        Amigo1.TextoCharla = "Amigo1: Como andan mis tios";
        Amigo2.TextoCharla = "Amigo2: Muy bien bro, pasando las materias";
        Amigo3.TextoCharla = "Amigo3: Que bien, quiza yo repruebe una";
        
        Amigo1.TextoDespedida = "Amigo1: Pues buenas chavos nos vemos";
        Amigo2.TextoDespedida = "Amigo2: Sale, nos vemos";
        Amigo3.TextoDespedida = "Amigo3: Camara yo aun me voy a quedar";
        
        //Simulando una charla
        System.out.println("Charla entre tres amigos:");
        System.out.println("");
        Amigo1.Saludar();
        Amigo2.Saludar();
        Amigo3.Saludar();
        System.out.println("");
        Amigo1.Charlar();
        Amigo2.Charlar();
        Amigo3.Charlar();
        System.out.println("");
        Amigo1.Despedir();
        Amigo2.Despedir();
        Amigo3.Despedir();
        System.out.println("");
        
        boolean Bandera = true;
        int Respuesta;
        int i;

        while(Bandera){
            for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                Fulanos[i] = new Persona();
            }
            Respuesta = menu();
            switch(Respuesta){
                
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el texto del saludo de cada amigo:");
                    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                    System.out.print("Dame el texto saludo " +(i+1)+ ":");
                    Fulanos[i].TextoSaludo = Leer.nextLine();
                    }

                break;
                
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el texto de la charla de cada amigo:");
                    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                    System.out.print("Dame el texto charla " +(i+1)+ ":");
                    Fulanos[i].TextoCharla = Leer.nextLine();
                    }

                break;
                
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el texto de la despedida de cada amigo:");
                    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                    System.out.print("Dame el texto despedida " +(i+1)+ ":");
                    Fulanos[i].TextoDespedida = Leer.nextLine();
                    }

                break;
                
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Introduzca el orden en el que se mostraran los mensajes:");
                    
                break;
                
                
                case 5:
                    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                    System.out.println("Texto saludo Amigo"+(i+1)+":"+Fulanos[i].TextoSaludo);
                    System.out.println("Texto charla Amigo"+(i+1)+":"+Fulanos[i].TextoCharla);
                    System.out.println("Texto despedida Amigo"+(i+1)+":"+Fulanos[i].TextoDespedida);
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case 6:
                    Bandera = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    static int menu(){
        Scanner LeerM = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op;
        
        System.out.println("   Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Cambiar Texto del Saludo");
        System.out.println("2. Cambiar Texto de la Charla");
        System.out.println("3. Cambiar Texto de la Despedida");
        System.out.println("4. Cambiar Orden de los Textos");
        System.out.println("5. Reproducir");
        System.out.println("6. Salir");
        System.out.print("Seleccione una opcion:");
        op = LeerM.nextInt();
        return op;
    }
}
```

Digamos que puedo hacer que el menú funcione y con el for puedo meter los datos de saludo, charla o despedida, pero no puedo hacer que se vean con el `case 5` y en este se imprime puro null, además que tampoco se como hacerlos cambiar de orden.

Al momento de ejecutar y seleccionar una opción del menú, como por ejemplo la 1, puedo meter las cosas del "saludo" para editarlas por así decirlo, pero al momento de ejecutar el case 5 para hacer que se vean los textos del case 1, no aparece lo que escribí y solo aparece null, incluso están desordenados los null ya que primero aparece todo de la persona 1 y luego todo de la persona 2 cuando debería de aparecer primero los 3 saludos, luego las 3 charlas y luego las 3 despedidas:

Ejemplo:
Texto saludo Amigo1:null
Texto charla Amigo1:null
Texto despedida Amigo1:null
Texto saludo Amigo2:null
Texto charla Amigo2:null
Texto despedida Amigo2:null
Texto saludo Amigo3:null
Texto charla Amigo3:null
Texto despedida Amigo3:null

Y me gustaría que aparecieran primero los 3 saludos, luego las 3 charlas y luego las 3 despedidas

Esta es la parte de la clase Persona para la primera parte de la conversación:

```
class Persona {
    String TextoSaludo;
    String TextoCharla;
    String TextoDespedida;

    void Saludar(){
        System.out.println(TextoSaludo);
    }
    void Charlar(){
        System.out.println(TextoCharla);
    }
    void Despedir(){
        System.out.println(TextoDespedida);
    }
}
```

Comment: Y el problema es...? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta (y el título también, ya que parece _clickbait_). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está al iniciar tu ciclo while:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  Fulanos[i] = new Persona();
}
```

Estas reiniciando las personas, entiendo que al eliminarlo dará un NullPointerException, este se debe a que no se llena el arreglo de fulanos.

```
Persona Amigo1 = new Persona();
Persona Amigo2 = new Persona();
Persona Amigo3 = new Persona();
Persona[] Fulanos = new Persona[3];
```

Te comparto una solución, primero debes ingresar a los amigos, dentro del arreglo de fulanos:

```
// Creando la instancia del objeto
Persona Amigo1 = new Persona();
Persona Amigo2 = new Persona();
Persona Amigo3 = new Persona();

Persona[] Fulanos = new Persona[3];
Fulanos[0] = Amigo1;
Fulanos[1] = Amigo2;
Fulanos[2] = Amigo3;
```

y eliminar la parte del for, que te comenté al principio.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    Fulanos[i] = new Persona();
}
```